# Timer Event Not firing C# UWP

Tags: c#

I have a UWP application and I can not seem to get my timed event to fire.

Below is the code:

```
public PresencePage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += PresencePage_Loaded;
    
}

private void TimedEvent()
{
    aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    aTimer.Interval = 20000;
    aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Timer_Elapsed);
    aTimer.AutoReset = true;

}
private async void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    SampleItems.Clear();

    List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
    List<PresenceModel> presences = new List<PresenceModel>();

    //Not firing
}


private async void PresencePage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SampleItems.Clear();

    //get mock
    //var data = await SampleDataService.GetMasterDetailDataUserAsync();
    List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
    List<PresenceModel> presences = new List<PresenceModel>();

    TimedEvent();
}
```

The timed event should fire and run `PresencePage` again to repopulate the lists.When I check the `TimedEvent()` is called but it just goes through and never calls `TimerElasped`.

ii) The timer runs to repopulate the employees and presence lists, is this the best way to repopulate these in UWP since it will like cause the whole page to be refreshed. Any suggestions will be welcome thanks.

Comment: Your code example is incomplete, but there's no evidence you ever start the timer. See duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start time with `aTimer.Enabled = true;`. Add it into your `TimedEvent()` or appropriate place to start timer. To stop timer you need to set `aTimer.Enabled = false;`

Refrence [Timer.Enabled Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.enabled?view=net-5.0#System_Timers_Timer_Enabled)

```
private void TimedEvent()
{
    aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    aTimer.Interval = 20000;
    aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Timer_Elapsed);
    aTimer.AutoReset = true;  
    // Add below line to start timer.
    aTimer.Enabled = true;  
}
```